# How two print two 3D objects together

Tags: graphics3d

I am trying to 3D print a torus with a curve running around it. This is what I tried:

```
G1 = ParametricPlot3D[{(4 + Sin[u]) Cos[v], (4 + Sin[u]) Sin[v], Cos[u]}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotPoints -> {7, 50},Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.2]]
G2 = ParametricPlot3D[{(4 + Sin[20 t]) Cos[t], (4 + Sin[20 t]) Sin[t], Cos[20 t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi] + .05}, PlotStyle -> Tube[.2], PlotPoints -> {7, 40}, Mesh -> All, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]], PlotRange -> All]
Show[G2, G1]
Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "TORUSWITHCURVE.stl"}], %]
```

It works, but the curve and the torus are not fused as one object. So when you go to print the model, there are places where it gets disconnected. Is there ay way to have two object merge into one? Perhaps if there is a fill tool I'm unaware of to just make the shape a solid? That might work. This might be better suited to a 3D printing forum, but I would ideally like to use Mathematica to formulate all of my 3D objects, so if I could figure out how to fix it on that end, that would be best. Thanks.

Comment: Please post code, not images ... unless they are images

Comment: What's wrong with the image?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/si_fueris_Romae,_Romano_vivito_more;_si_fueris_alibi,_vivito_sicut_ibi#Latin

Comment: @Dr.belisarius I think I will save it to my favorite quotes

Comment: Not trying to be snarky but seriously, why is an image any less valid than the code?

Comment: @user46348 Because when someone wants to try your code, s/he has to retype it. That's fairly uncourteous

Comment: Ah that makes sense!

Comment: Why not simply increase the radii of the torus and curve by a few percent?

Comment: The code above perfectly works for me (Mma 10.3, Win7).

Comment: For me as well, on Mathematica 10.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: edit: I think OP wants something like DiscretizeGraphics[]